# Absoft Fortran 77 Linking Error: error LNK2001:unresolved external symbol _rand_ and _seed_

Tags: linker, fortran

I am getting 2 linking errors which I think have to do with a library not being linked properly using the Absoft Fortran Pro 2014 compiler. The function that I believe is causing the error is:

```
       real FUNCTION RAND(i)
       integer i
       real x


       IF (i-1) 20, 10, 20 
10      CALL SEED(-1)
        i=i+1
20      continue
       CALL RANDOM(x)
       RAND=x
       END
```

Is there a library that I need to include for the random number generator to work? If so, how do I do that?

The error messages are:

```
RAND.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _random_
RAND.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _seed_
```

Thank you,
David.

Comment: How are you linking it?

Comment: I use the build tool in the project screen to compile which I assume does the linking.

Comment: Which version and OS?

Comment: I'm using windows 7 64 bit, the Absoft version is 14.0.4 and the IDE version is 2.2.

Comment: Those aren't Fortran 77 standard routine names - which library are they in?

Comment: I think it is a library from an earlier version of the Absoft compiler that is no longer included in this new version.